# How to Add Environment Variables to Hostinger?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, hosting

My site was built in React, and I am hosting it on Hostinger. I am using Express.js for the back-end, which is primarily responsible for making calls to Chat GPT's API.

I have my GPT API Key in a .env file, which is included in the .gitignore

I am not sure how to upload the API Key (.env) to Hostinger without risking the exposure of my Key.

Apparently Hostinger used to have an "environment variables" section in their advanced settings for this exact scenario, but I don't see that anywhere.

How can I get my .env file onto Hostinger without risking the exposure of my API Key?

Comment: React should not see your key. That is something only your Express server should be able to access.